# How to sum the size of documents within a time interval?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm attempting to estimate the sum of size of n documents across an index using below query :

```
GET /events/_search
{
  "query": {
            "bool":{
                    "must": [
                        {"range": {"ts": {"gte": "2022-10-10T00:00:00Z", "lt": "2022-10-21T00:00:00Z"}}}
                    ]
                }
        },
  "aggs": {
    "total_size": {
"sum": {
        "field": "doc['_source'].bytes"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns documents but the size of the aggregation is 0 :

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "total_size" : {
      "value" : 0.0
    }
  }
```

How to sum the size of documents within a time interval ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to actually add another field that contains the real source size at indexing time.

However, if you want to run it once to see how it looks like, you can leverage runtime fields to compute this at search time, just know that it can put a heavy burden on your cluster. Since the Painless scripting language doesn't yet provide a way to transform the source document to the same JSON you sent at indexing time, we can only approximate the value you're looking for by stringifying the `_source` Hashmap, yielding this:

```
GET /events/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "source.size": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": """
        def size = params._source.toString().length() * 8;
        emit(size);
      """
    }
  },
  "query": {
        "bool":{
                "must": [
                    {"range": {"ts": {"gte": "2022-10-10T00:00:00Z", "lt": "2022-10-21T00:00:00Z"}}}
                ]
            }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "size": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "source.size"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another way is to install the [Mapper size plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size.html) so that you can make use of the `_size` field computed at indexing time.

Comment: thanks but that returns 0.0 also. I'm using ELK 7.17

Comment: Can you share what you get from `GET events/_mapping/fields/bytes` ?

Comment: {
  "error" : "no handler found for uri [/events/_mapping/fields/bytes?pretty=true] and method [GET]"
}

Comment: Oh, I see, `bytes` is not a field, but you want the byte size of the `_source`, sorry I misread your question

Comment: thanks, 'def size = params._source.toString().length();' this returns the length of the document, I'm attempting to calculate the size. Can I do something like 'def size = params._source.bytes;' ?

Comment: You can simply multiply by 8 (for simplicity) so you get the size in bytes. There's no such thing as `.bytes` available... As I said, you should compute this value at **indexing time** and add it as a new field in your document or use the "size" plugin, see my updated answer

Comment: I see, so each character takes 8 bits, so number of bytes of a string is (lengthOfString * 8) ?

Comment: It depends, with UTF-8 each character can take 8, 16, 24, or 23 bits but the String.length() method should account for that since that's what the [mapper plugin does](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/plugins/mapper-size/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/size/SizeFieldMapper.java#L92)